# Is there a better way to do this Concatenation in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, concatenation, coalesce

I've got the following SQL statement that does a subquery concatenation. If you notice, it uses `FOR XML ..` which .. well .. gives me the shivers a bit :: I feel like it's some code-smell.

Is there a better way to do this with SQL Server 2008 ?

```
SELECT a.CityId AS LocationId, a.City,
     STUFF(
        (SELECT ', ' + x.County
         FROM [dbo].[CountiesView] x
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[CityCounties] y ON x.CountyId = y.CountyId
         WHERE y.CityId = a.CityId
         FOR XML PATH (''))
     , 1, 2, '')
FROM [dbo].[CitiesView] a
    where a.StateCode = 'NY'
```

What this code is doing is it listing all the cities (and their counties) for the state of New York. Because a city can exist in 1 or more counties, I wish to CONCATENATE the County names ... otherwise i'll get 1 city row per county (which I don't want).

Can this be refactored, better?

I tried to use COALESCE but had no luck.

Comment: No, that **is** the best way to do it - code-smell or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Better" is in the eye of the beholder. I haven't seen a better way to do this in SQL Server 2005+, but I haven't been looking hard.

The very best way is probably to [program your own aggregate function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91e6taax%28VS.80%29.aspx). I think I'd rather maintain this query.

Answer (score 1):

As you don't care about `ORDER` you can use a CLR custom aggregate to do this. It may well perform better than the XML method and your current approach won't deal well if any Counties contain the `&` symbol (or `<` and `>` but I guess that is unlikely!)

Comment: Yeah, I even tested that out earlier on today (before I made this post) and can confirm that. That's the first thing I thought of when I saw the `XML PATH` syntax. (I didn't say anything because I didn't want to pollute the question).